# How to compile Arduino Framework with GNU

Tags: compile, compiler

I'm wondering if it's possible to use GNU (g++) to compile a arduino Sketch.

I wanna be able to unit test my code with `catch2`.

`g++ -std=c++11 <filename>` works well with catch2, but I obviously does not recognize Arduino's framework (Strings, Serial etc).

What I think is, maybe if I use Arduino's compiler [ which is compatible with -std=c++11 I would be able to do run the catch2 with the Arduino framework.

Does anyone knows where to find Arduino's compiler? or how to make GNU accept Arduino's framework?

Comment: Never heard of "catch2". But the  "arduino" compiler *is* g++. avr-g++ to be precise. If you're using Linux you can install it as a system package if you like.

Comment: But if you're asking if you can compile Arduino code to run natively on a PC, no, not without using a core and board written specifically for the PC. You might look at Wiring-Pi as a starting point for that.

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=662682.msg4637993#msg4637993

Comment: Some keywords that may help: "arduino-builder", "Sudar Arduino Makefile", "simavr".